# Java 8 int array to map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert **int array** to

```
Map<Integer,Integer>
```

using Java 8 stream api

```
int[] nums={2, 7, 11, 15, 2, 11, 2};
Map<Integer,Integer> map=Arrays
                .stream(nums)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e,1));
```

I want to get a map like below, key will be integer value, value will be total count of each key

> map={2->3, 7->1, 11->2, 15->1}

compiler complains "**no instance(s) of type variable(s) T, U exist so that Integer confirms to Function**"

appreciate any pointers to resolve this

Comment: `Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> 1, Integer::sum));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to box the `IntStream` and then use `groupingBy` value to get the count:

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays
        .stream(nums)
        .boxed() // this
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

or use `reduce` as:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays
        .stream(nums)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e,
                Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if the map value is just 1 instead of key count, is it possible to use Collectors.toMap(e->e,1), by modifying it

Comment: @Buddhi, No, should be `...Collectors.toMap(e->e,v->1)...`

Comment: @HadiJ but you’d need `Collectors.toMap(e->e, v->1, Integer::sum)` in this specific case, to handle the duplicates.

Comment: @Holger, yeah, I meant for this `...toMap(e->e,1)`. thanks for clearing

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `.boxed()` on your Stream to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`. Then you can use `Collectors.groupingby()` and `Collectors.summingInt()` to count the values:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish counting the ints without boxing the `int` values into a `Map<Integer, Integer>` or `Map<Integer, Long>`. If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), you can convert an `IntStream` to an `IntBag` as follows.

```
int[] nums = {2, 7, 11, 15, 2, 11, 2};
IntBag bag = IntBags.mutable.withAll(IntStream.of(nums));
System.out.println(bag.toStringOfItemToCount());
```

Outputs:

```
{2=3, 7=1, 11=2, 15=1}
```

You can also construct the `IntBag` directly from the `int` array.

```
IntBag bag = IntBags.mutable.with(nums);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.