# Convert an array of numbers to Map using Java Streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following array in Java:

```
int arr[] = {4,5,6};
```

I want to convert it into a `java.util.Map<K,V>` instance that has the index of the array as keys and the value at index as values for the Map. Like so,

```
0 = 4
1 = 5
2 = 6
```

I have tried the following:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> arr[k]));
```

But this results in compilation errors like:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,capture#1-of ?,Map<Object,Object>> to Supplier<R>
```

and

```
The method collect(Supplier<R>, ObjIntConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Object,?,Map<Object,Object>>)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

**I am just going over all the indices and then mapping them to keys and values where am I going wrong ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 int array to map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406621/java-8-int-array-to-map)

Comment: `IntStream` has only one `collect` method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer). Try to map it to a `Stream<Integer>` like this: `IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> Integer.valueOf(arr[k.intValue()])));`.

Comment: Try to use a Stream of Integer by using IntStream#boxed instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
int arr[] = {4,5,6};
Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), k -> arr[k]));
resultMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue()));
```

**Output:**

```
0 = 4
1 = 5
2 = 6
```

Comment: Integer#valueOf is not necessary.

Comment: @Jason thanks, I have updated answer

Comment: No worries, also instead of using k -> k you can just use Function#identity to use the input value of the Stream and the key of the map.

Comment: @NitinBisht What is `Function.identity()` ?

Comment: @ng.newbie `Function.identity()` returns a function that always returns its input argument.

Comment: @ng.newbie you can also use it like `Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> arr[k])`. Although to understand it more you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/8258942

Answer (score 2):

You are using IntStream which is unboxed. You need to use `.boxed()`.

If your array is ordered, yo can do:

```
int arr[] = {4,5,6};

Map<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> Arrays.binarySearch(arr, i), Function.identity()));

map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue()));
```

If it's not ordered you can do:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> arr[i]));
```

Comment: What is `Function.identity()` ??

Comment: It is similar to i -> i (but not the same). From javadoc: "Returns a function that always returns its input argument.". If you want to get more info, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t

Answer (score 1):

You have to box the IntStream and use groupingBy value to get the wanted count.

Try this:

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays
        .stream(arr)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions.

**1. For-each loop**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    map.put(i, arr[i]);
}
```

In my opinion, this is the most clear in terms of readability.

---

**2. `IntStream` with a range of the array length**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> arr[i]));
```

This seems like your original attempt. You need either to box with `boxed()` to `Stream<Integer>` in order to use `collect` with a single `Collector`.

---

**3. `Stream::iterate` and `Stream::limit`**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
    .limit(arr.length)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> arr[i]));
```

It's a simple endless generation of an increasing sequence by one limited by the length of the array.