# How to use keys/values from regular array to create associative array in Java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm just barely learning Java and need to accomplish something in Java 8, but I'm struggling to figure out the most efficient way to do it (coming from a PHP background). Essentially I'm trying to give it a regular array, run some calculations, and then save some of those values in a new array where the original key is preserved.

So basically the original array is something like:

```
0 => 3
1 => 5
2 => 6
3 => 8
```

and the new array will be an associative array where the keys are specifically assigned like:

```
1 => 5
3 => 8
```

In order to help myself visualize it in something I'm more familiar with, I've gotten everything I need working in PHP, and it looks something like this:

```
$array = array( 8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 15 );

$new_array = array();

foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {

    // Calculate something and build new array, for example...
    if ( 5 > $value ) {

        $new_value = $value + 5;

        $new_array[ $key ] = $new_value;
    }
}
```

So in this example, `$new_array` would be:

```
1 => 8
2 => 7
4 => 6
```

I would swear I've seen something where I can do just a basic `for` loop and access `key` and `value` but I can't find where I read that, and everything else I'm finding now talks about iterating through "hash maps" using `forEach()`, so that seems like the standard approach, but when I try `array.forEach((k, v) -> // Calculations....` it tells me that it "cannot find symbol" for `array` in that context, which is being set immediately prior as `int[] array = { // numbers }`. As I'm understanding it, I have to convert the array to a hash map in order to be able to use a key/value pair in the foreach, but apparently I'm doing something wrong there as well...

So I guess here are my questions...

1. Can I use a basic `for` loop for this or I need to convert the array to a hash map in order to access the key/value pairs? How? I don't need to use any specific method, just looking for the most efficient.
2. I have `import java.util.Arrays;` for other reasons - do I need to import something else?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE -------------------------

To clarify, I'll need to do something similar later in the code again using `$new_array` as the source, so I need to be able to get the keys and not just the iteration count.

So for example if I were to wrap the `foreach` in a `while` loop, where the first time it starts with `$array` and each subsequent time it sets `$array` as `$new_array` to run the calculations again.

So in other words, I can't rely on the iteration count to match the keys.

Comment: Use a basic `for` loop and store the result in a Map using the index variable as the key.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Later in the code I'll need to do something similar with the `$new_array` though, so the counter won't match the keys. Is there a way to specifically get the key value?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but notice that the variable you call $new_array is a Map in java. It should probably work the same in java as in php

Comment: Sorry - I'll add an update to the question and see if I can explain.

Comment: I still don’t understand, you will have the keys if you use a Map. And if you want to use a for each loop instead then why not manually keep track of the index with a variable. Or use a Map instead of an array to start with

Comment: Well this is all going to be inside a function which is passed `int[] array`, so it sounds like I need to first convert the initial array to a map... thanks, I'll see if I can figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use Stream API to convert array into map in a functional way:

- use `IntStream.range` to create a stream of integers
- collected into map using `Collectors.toMap`:

For a new map, `filter` operation can be applied to select values less than 5.

```java
// these imports to be added
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

int [] array = {8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 15};
Map<Integer, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, array.length) // stream of int indexes
                                     .boxed() // stream of Integer
                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                         i -> i,        // use index as key
                                         i -> array[i]  // get array element as value
                                     ));

Map<Integer, Integer> mapNew = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                                        .boxed()
                                        .filter(i -> array[i] < 5)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> array[i] + 5));

System.out.println("old map:" + map);
// printing each entry in new map using lambda
mapNew.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));

// use common for loop by entries
System.out.println("----");
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : mapNew.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Output:

```
old map:{0=8, 1=3, 2=2, 3=9, 4=1, 5=15}
1 -> 8
2 -> 7
4 -> 6
----
1 => 8
2 => 7
4 => 6
```

Comment: Trying this out - I'm getting a 'cannot find symbol' on Map. Do I need to import something?

Comment: yes, sure, I updated the answer.  These imports needed: `import java.util.*;` to get `Map` and `import java.util.stream.*;` to get `IntStream`, `Collectors`

Comment: This may be a different question but is there a way to set up the foreach not as a lambda so I can use local variables inside it (that were set outside of it)?

Comment: Sure, `foreach` loop for map iterate over `map.entrySet()`

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Last question - the array is small but if it gets quite large - say 10,000 - do you know if there would be any performance issues from calling something like `getKey()` or it that pretty fast?

Comment: HashMap has constant O(1) complexity of accessing elements, so there should not be any performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular `for` loop:

```
int [] array = {8, 3, 2, 9, 1, 15};
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

// Print the results
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (5 > array[i]) {
        map.put(i, array[i] + 5);
    }
}
        
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I updated my question - I have to get the actual keys as they may not match the iteration count. Is there a way to modify this to do that?

Comment: @Shoelaced If there are keys then it is not an array. The source data is in a map?

Comment: The initial `$array` is just a regular array, but it sounds like `$new_array` output will be a map, and since I'll need to run the same foreach again on `$new_array`, it sounds like I need to first convert `$array` to a map and go from there?

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what you need to do. Arrays and maps are (obviously) very different and are accessed using different semantics so the same loop won't work on both.

Comment: I see... how would I convert the array to a map? I can search around but if you can update your answer that'd be helpful too.

Comment: With Java8, you can use streams ([Java 8 int array to map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56406621)) or a simple loop: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) map.put(i, array[i]);`